# Given a tree, calculate longest path in this tree having nodes in path with same set bit

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have given a tree (N Nodes) and at each tree node given a number. We need to find out the largest sum we can get by traversing a path in this tree such that each node in the path is having same number of set bits.

Given, array A, where A[i] denotes the value given to ith Node;
Given two array, B and C where ith element represent the ith edge connecting nodes B[i] to C[i].

**Input:**
A: 16 1 7 16 2 3 2 
B: 1 1 1 4 4 6
C: 2 3 4 5 6 7

**Output:**
35 (2->1->4->2)

**I tried:**
I created adjency list using B and C. Also, created another array bit[n] where bit[i] represents no. of set bit at node ith. Then, one by one iterating over each node (fixing it as starting path) and recursively try to calculate max sum.

```
    int calpath(int A[], ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al,int u,int bit[],int parent){

            int ans=0;
            int currbit=bit[u];
            for(int i=0;i<al.get(u).size();i++){
                  int v = al.get(u).get(i);
                  if(parent!=v){
                       if(bit[v]==currbit){
                            ans = Math.max(calpath(A,al,v,bit,u),ans);
                       }
                  }
            }
            return (ans+A[u])%(1000000007);

    } 


//-----------------At main-----------------

for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
    ans = Math.max(calpath(A,al,i,bit,-1),ans);
}
```

This is however, naive way to solve the above problem but still its giving me Wrong Answer. What is the problem with above code? Is there better approach to solve this?

I can't post the link to online judge as test got ended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a graph problem wherein you need to find maximum distance nodes having same set bits using dfs.

Helpful:
[Find Longest Path in Directed Graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/)

Advice: Add nodes to adjacency list only if no of set bits are same. This will reduce unnecessary comparisons.